# Calling iprintf causes image to fail

Tags: c, gcc, arm, newlib

I am building a small bare metal test program for a Cortex-M3 (in a SmartFusion2). I am using the GCC ARM Embedded toolchain (5-2016-q1-update). The first thing I do in my `main` function is to initialise a UART for debug output. I then output some characters directly to the UART to indicate boot. This UART is also used within the newlib syscalls in `_write_r`. The next line in my `main` function calls `printf`. If I leave this as a call to `printf`, as it has no arguments, the compiler optimises it to a call to `puts` (even though I am specifying -O0). This works correctly. If I make the call to `iprintf` the compiler does not optimise it, and now I see no output at all, even from the earlier call directly to the UART. This suggests that something is going wrong during start up, but I have no idea what.

In summary:

```
void main(void)
{
    UART_init();
    UART_printBuffer("Starting...\r\n");
    printf("Working\r\n");
    while(1);
}
```

works correctly and `nm` tells me that the `printf` call has become `puts`. I see the two lines of output as expected.

However for the following code I see no output at all:

```
void main(void)
{
    UART_init();
    UART_printBuffer("Starting...\r\n");
    iprintf("Working\r\n");
    while(1);
}
```

Any clues on where to start debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: I've just discovered that switching to newlib nano (`--specs=newlib.nano`) makes this issue go away. I'm still confused and would like to know why this is.